# Add user on Jessie that can log on to FTP but has no shell

Tags: shell, ssh, permissions, ftp

I have set up a vsftpd server and I used chroot to keep users locked inside their home directories, which works just fine. 
I have since tried to edit the passwd file to set the default shell to `/bin/false` and even `/user/sbin/nologin` in order to keep users from logging in with SSH and viewing my folder structure (even if they lack `rwx` permissions).

While I am not surprised the 2nd option does not work I wonder why I can also not login to the account with an FTP client if I set the default shell to anything other than `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

How would I go about having the account be a valid login for FTP but with no SSH access?

Comment: The `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups`, and `AllowGroups` settings mentioned in `sshd_config(5)` seem promising, among other means.

Comment: @thrig you should post that as an answer, and might want to elaborate a bit on AllowUsers, since this is a whitelist of SSH users (unlike DenyUsers which is a blacklist and typically would need more maintenance)

Answer (score 2):

For ftp access without shell or other access, vsftp supports virtual users. The solution basically amounts to using PAM to operate on a different user list, and adjusting vsftpd config to honor that list. There is a detailed article here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd

The article mentions needing "db_util"; on Jessie you can find several versions like so:

```
apt-cache search '^db.*-util$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Via OpenSSH configuration, one could disable access in `sshd_config`:

```
DenyUsers joe bob
```

Though it might be more sensible to have a list of folks who are allowed to SSH, and then deny everyone else:

```
AllowGroups wheel staff
```

Or instead to lump all the ftp users into a particular group (say, `nossh`), and deny that. It is easier to change group memberships than to always be editing `sshd_config`.

```
DenyGroup nossh
```

another way to slice this (on Linux) is to adjust the PAM configuration, for example to use `pam_access.so` for `/etc/pam.d/ssh` (plus appropriate `access.conf(5)` configuration) but not for FTP.